# How to make ModalBottomSheetLayout to use the newest state for sheetContent?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to show a timestamp (or any strings that can be updated in general) inside a sheetContent of the ModalBottomSheetLayout that is shown by clicking on a floating action button. However, that timestamp is only updated once: the first time that the sheet is shown. If I close the sheet (through onSave in the code) and open it again, the timestamp stays the same instead of showing the newest timestamp. I think I maybe missing "remember" or "mutableState" somehow but I am not able to get it to work.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AskQuestionTheme {
                val modalBottomSheetState =
                    rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        FloatingActionButton(
                            onClick = { scope.launch { modalBottomSheetState.show() } }) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Rounded.Add,
                                contentDescription = "add"
                            )
                        }
                    }) {
                    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
                        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                        sheetContent = {
                            var t = Date().toString()
                            MySheet(
                                str = t,
                                onSave = {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        modalBottomSheetState.hide()
                                    }
                                },
                                onCancel = { scope.launch { modalBottomSheetState.hide() } })
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("hello")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MySheet(str: String, onSave: () -> Unit, onCancel: () -> Unit) {
    Column {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Rounded.Close,
                contentDescription = "edit",
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart).clickable { onCancel() })
            Button(onClick = onSave, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd)) {
                Text("save")
            }
        }
        Text(str)
        Spacer(Modifier.height(100.dp))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways for me. Up to you which select)

First variant. Added a new property `var t by remember { mutableStateOf(Date().toString()) }` and change its before showing `ModalBottomSheetLayout`. It is an update code
`t = Date().toString()`.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AskQuestionTheme {
                val modalBottomSheetState =
                    rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                var t by remember { mutableStateOf(Date().toString()) }

                Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        FloatingActionButton(
                            onClick = {
                                scope.launch {
                                    t = Date().toString()
                                    modalBottomSheetState.show()
                                }
                            }) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Rounded.Add,
                                contentDescription = "add"
                            )
                        }
                    }) {
                    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
                        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                        sheetContent = {
                            MySheet(
                                str = t,
                                onSave = {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        modalBottomSheetState.hide()
                                    }
                                },
                                onCancel = { scope.launch { modalBottomSheetState.hide() } })
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("hello")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second variant. Now you can see `LaunchedEffect`. Code inside this block is triggered when this value `modalBottomSheetState.direction` changes. Inside this block we update a `date`.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AskQuestionTheme {
                val modalBottomSheetState =
                    rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        FloatingActionButton(
                            onClick = { scope.launch { modalBottomSheetState.show() } }) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Rounded.Add,
                                contentDescription = "add"
                            )
                        }
                    }) {
                    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
                        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
                        sheetContent = {

                            var t by remember { mutableStateOf(Date().toString()) }
                            
                            LaunchedEffect(modalBottomSheetState.direction) {
                                if (modalBottomSheetState.direction == -1f) {
                                    t = Date().toString()
                                }
                            }

                            MySheet(
                                str = t,
                                onSave = {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        modalBottomSheetState.hide()
                                    }
                                },
                                onCancel = { scope.launch { modalBottomSheetState.hide() } })
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("hello")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```